# how does jsperf handle browser errors?

Tags: browser, error-handling, jsperf

I want to test natively implemented es6 features.

If a browser does not support that feature, I would like the test not to show in the browserscope graph.

Will this "just work" (jsperf cancel the tests and not show in graph) or is there a special way to cancel jsperf tests?

I'll try this, naturally, but I wonder if there is a "jsperf way" to manage this.